# Debugging Spring Code in STS (Eclipse)

Tags: eclipse, debugging, spring-tool-suite

I am used to working in Netbeans, where I can start a project in debug mode, alter some code, and hit the "Apply Code changes" button.

at the moment I am working in Eclipse (Spring Tools Suite) and I would like to do something similar.

I found [This article](https://javathought.wordpress.com/2009/04/18/debugging-in-eclipse-vs-netbeans/) which suggests that Eclipse does it automagically if Project -> Build automatically is set, but that is not my experience. (regarding Spring Boot projects, which is what I am currently working with)

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Are your break points working? Does the debugger find your source files when stopping at a break point? Could be a build path setup problem.

Comment: Break points are working fine. it's the ability to modify code running in the JVM I am missing - ie when you are debugging, and you inspect your code to find an error, fix he item in code, apply the settings and step through to find the next (no stopping the debugging session needed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Eclipse and in combination with the Spring Boot Devtools, you have two options to deal with this situation.

One if the ability of the JVM to swap-in code changes while you are debugging without loosing the state of the application. This works in Eclipse out-of-the-box when you have "Build Automatically" enabled and do a code change after you hit a breakpoint. Usually the JVM drops the current execution frame and continues the execution at the beginning of the current method invocation.

BUT: This works for minor code changes only (changing the implementation of a method, for example). Most changes to the source code can't be hot-swapped by the JVM. If the IDE tries to do that, you will get an error message that this is not possible with the question whether you want to restart the JVM, stop it, or continue without the code changes. This is a limitation of the JVM, not directly of the IDE.

The other option is to go with the Spring Boot Devtools. Once they are on the classpath of the app and you change a class on the classpath of the project (which happens automatically if you have the "Build Automatically" enabled), the Boot Devtools will detect those changes and re-start the boot app automatically. This doesn't cause the JVM to be restarted, just the boot app part of it. Therefore it is much faster than starting the full JVM. BUT: you are loosing the state of the application. From the debugging perspective, it is the same as if you would restart the app, it is just faster. But you can't do what while sitting on a breakpoint and expecting the app to continue with the same stack frame.

There are other tools like JRebel that allow for more sophisticated code changes to be hot-swapped into the running app and there are also plugins for Eclipse to use JRebel, for example, but that is another story.